A feature to add a Service feature on Elementor WordPress)
Please I need help!!!
I’m working on a WordPress site where I need to implement a feature that allows users to unhide specific content on their dashboard when they click a button on a separate services page. Here’s a brief overview of what I’m trying to achieve and the issues I'm encountering:
Objective:
On the user dashboard, certain content containers are initially hidden.
Users should be able to click a button on a services page to “add” a service, which will unhide the corresponding container on their dashboard.
The hidden container should remain visible to the user even after a page refresh or logs out and log back in.
Using WpCode -
JavaScript Functionality:
I have implemented a JavaScript function that sends an AJAX request to the server when a button is clicked. The request aims to update the user meta data to indicate that the service should be visible.
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.unhide-service-btn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var serviceId = $(this).data('service-id');

        $.ajax({
            url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'unhide_service',
                serviceId: serviceId,
                nonce: my_ajax_object.nonce
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log('Response:', response);
                if (response.success) {
                    $('#service-' + serviceId).removeClass('hidden-service');
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log('Error:', status, error);
            }
        });
    });
});

Also using WpCode
PHP Backend Handling:
I’ve set up an AJAX handler in PHP to process the request and update the user meta data. The handler checks the nonce for security.
Enqueue Script:
I’m enqueueing the JavaScript file and localizing it to pass AJAX URL and nonce.
function enqueue_custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_localize_script('custom-js', 'my_ajax_object', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('unhide_service_nonce')  // Add nonce
    ));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_scripts');

function unhide_service_callback() {
    // Check nonce for security
    check_ajax_referer('unhide_service_nonce', 'nonce');

    // Retrieve and process AJAX data
    $service_id = isset($_POST['serviceId']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['serviceId']) : '';

    // Store user preference (you might use user meta or another storage method)
    if ($service_id) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'visible_service_' . $service_id, true);
    }

    wp_send_json_success();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_unhide_service', 'unhide_service_callback');


you forget to write your issue. edit your question to explain the result you have now and to show us what the debug displays.
